# Overlay on a section of webpage but keep the other sections active to user's actions

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I need to place an overlay on the webpage in a certain area but need to keep active the other section of the page. I was trying to do that with the help of `LightBox` provided by primefaces components but could not achieve what I wanted.
I could not make active the un-overlayed section of the webpage.

Any help on how I can achieve that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`<p:dialog modal="true">`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf).

Comment: I want the content that is being placed in the dialog box to be retrieved lazily when the corresponding button is pressed. I am actually trying to show a discussion Post's entire content inside this overlay element. While at first the user is shown a list of all posts overviews. On clicking on an post overview, the full data for that post must be retrieved and shown in this overlay element. Please let me know how I can achieve lazy loading in this case. Thanks so much!

Comment: Use `<p:commandButton action="#{bean.loadDataForDialog}" update="dialogContent" oncomplete="dialog.show()" />`.